# Serializer - Including extra context in Django Rest Framework 3 not working

Tags: django-rest-framework

The documentation states:

> You can provide arbitrary additional context by passing a `context` argument when instantiating the serializer.

Ok, so let's do that:

```
serializer = AccountSerializer(account, context={'foo':'bar'})
```

The documentation then states:

> The context dictionary can be used within any serializer field logic by accessing the `self.context` attribute.

Ok, so let's do that:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    custom_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'custom_field')

    def get_custom_field(self, obj):
        print('Context:', self.context)
        foo = self.context.get('foo')
        print('Foo:', foo)
        ...
        return "custom data"
```

Those print statements result in:

```
Context: {'request': <rest_framework.request.Request object at 0x1127d3160>, 'format': None, 'view': <account.api.views.AccountView object at 0x1127c4f98>

Foo: None
```

What am I doing wrong here? No matter what the context is not modified with the extra context desired.

Comment: i think that the problem will be somewhere where you actually use the serializer.  As it has already some context in it, result of a view's get_serializer method -  it seems that it is used in a view. Can you include the view where you use it ? You might need to set the context in the view little bit differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are showing the result of the serializer being used in the [DRF GenericAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods). The [get_serializer_context](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0e10d32fb122619a7977909536b642d09603192a/rest_framework/generics.py#L132) method by default provides the context entries 'request', 'view' and 'format' and the context argument of the serializer constructor is ineffective.
If you want to add more things to the context there, you also need to override it **in the view**:

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
    context = super().get_serializer_context()
    context['foo'] = 'bar'
    return context
```

Comment: I just realized this based on @Enthusiast Martin's answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Linovia, could you help me look into this please. It is a similar question but the solution here doesn't work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039305/how-to-pass-extra-context-to-django-rest-framework-serializers