# Django REST framework: passing additional contextual data from view to serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django REST framework view (`generics.GenericAPIView`). In it, I want to pass contextual data (the original request received by the view) to a serializer.

As per [Serializer - Including extra context in Django Rest Framework 3 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188500/serializer-including-extra-context-in-django-rest-framework-3-not-working), I've overridden the `get_serializer_context()` method inherited from Rest Framework's `GenericAPIView`.

My view looks like this:

```
class MyView(GenericAPIView):
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context.update({"original_request": self.request})
        return context

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        my_object = ... get object from database ...

        serializer = MySerializer(my_instance=my_object, validated_data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            logger.warning("MyView/put() - request: " + str(request))
            .... other stuff ...
```

My serializer:

```
class MySerializer():
    def update(self, my_instance, validated_data):
        logger.warning("MySerializer/update() - context: " + str(self.context))
        ... other stuff ...
```

My view's logs shows that the request details are present:

```
MyView/put() - request: <rest_framework.request.Request: PUT '<URL>'>
```

... but they are not passed to the serializer:

```
MySerializer/update() - context: {}
```

I'm suspecting that it's because the `self.request` value in `get_serializer_context()` is not populated or is not the same as the one supplied in the view's `put()` method.

I've also tried including the context data directly during the instantiation of the serializer, as per https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context but that didn't work either - again, the contextual data was not passed from the view to the serializer.

How can I supply the additional contextual data to the serializer for individual requests via `generics.GenericAPIView`, please?

Many thanks for any information.

Comment: Is your code correct? At least `class MySerializer():` should be a child of one of `DRF` `Serializer` classes (`from rest_framework import serializers; class MySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):`). Please provide correct reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the serializer class directly and in that situation you have to pass the `context` manually

```
class MyView(GenericAPIView):
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context.update({"original_request": self.request})
        return context

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = MySerializer(
            instance,
            data=request.data,
            partial=False,
            context=self.get_serializer_context()
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

But, I would consider using the `get_serializer(...)` method to get the serializer instance

```
class MyView(GenericAPIView):
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context.update({"original_request": self.request})
        return context

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=False)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```